# Show Comment in Cell for most recent modification - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a total novice at this Google Scripts thing and I have been playing around with a script in order to show a comments box for every cell that gets updated and by which user.

So, for example I have a list of Urls in Column A, and I have various tasks in columns b, c, d, e, f.

When a task is complete I want the person who completed the task to update the sheet with a simple "yes" (or even a drop down selection/checkbox). When this is done, I would like a comment to be created/updated stating the date and user who updated that particular cell.

The script I am currently using goes like this: -

```
function onEdit(e)

{ 
  // Get all information, Cell, Date, User

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  var cell = event.source.getActiveRange();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy");

  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();

  //Write to Cell Comment

  cell.setComment(date + " User:" + user);

}
```

I am having 2 issues with this: -

1. This totally works for me, but when I share the sheet with others,
   the comment box display's the date of the update but not the user.
2. When someone overwrites in a cell that has been updated by the
   script, the comment bos does not update to show this.

Your help here would be most appreciated...

Let me know if you need more information. Thank in advance to anyone who wishes to help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

I changed the script to show getEffectiveUser instead of getActiveUser and hey presto it works!!

:-)

Answer (score 1):

I use the same function and it's perfectly working for me (I always retrieve the username). You may encounter an issue because your spreadsheet is available for anonymous users.

if someone overwrite a cell it's normal to update the comment, what you could do is retrieve the previous comment and sum it with the new comment. Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var comment = r.getComment().replace("Last modified by: ","previously modified by");
  r.setComment("Last modified by: " +Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()+" on: "+(new Date())+comment);
}
```

Comment: hmmm strange...

I like your script, its great...

The sheet has been shared with only 2 other users and is set as private so not sure why it isn't showing the user who made the edit....

any ideas?

Comment: I believe I understood the problem, you are trying to share with a user that is on a different domain (it only seems to be working within the same domain - I haven't tryed with a gmail free email adress). Sorry but I do not know how to make it work across different domain.